# Payara 5.2020.4 didn't start

Tags: java, java-8, payara, payara-micro

I've **`jdk1.8.0_171`** installed on my windows 10, 64bit OS , yesterday I've downloaded `Payara Micro Community 5.2020.4` and added the server on `Netbeans 8.2`  , but when I try to start the sever NetBeans Payara server log shows following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class [9|]--add-opens=java.logging.java.util.logging=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Need clues to resolve this error

Thanks in advance

Comment: First try updating Netbeans cos there are some issues related with this https://github.com/payara/ecosystem-netbeans-plugin/issues/16

Comment: This type of error is triggered by Payara Server and not Payara Micro. Aren't you working with Payara Server? Payara Micro is just a JAR file that you execute on command line, via a maven plugin or add to your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a change in Payara Server configuration that's not compatible with how the older version of the Netbeans Payara (GlassFish) plugin launches Payara Server. The plugin uses a hacky mechanism that reads the domain configuration and launches the Java process of Payara Server directly instead of using the asadmin launcher.

You can easily fix this by editing the `domain.xml` file in `glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml`. Just remove all jvm-option elements where you find `[` and `]` brackets. These define the Java version for which the JVM option is applicable. Usually this is for running on JDK 9+, so it's safe to remove those options if you run on Java 8.

So, remove this option and all similar options:

```
<jvm-option>[9|]--add-opens=java.logging.java.util.logging=ALL-UNNAMED</jvm-option>
```

Upgrading Netbeans to the latest version 12.1 also fixes this problem as Netbeans has been updated to understand this change in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I have got a similar problem with **jdk1.8.0_311** , **payara-5.2021.10** on **netbeans 8.2** . payara start successfully in a terminal with command :

```
glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

, but when I start the server inside netbeans, i have some errors :

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseOpenJSSE'
Unrecognized VM option 'HotswapAgent=core'
Unrecognized option: -Xlog:redefine+class*=info
```

The solution by *OndroMih* works fine.
I have removed this lines in domain.xml. "`glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml`"

> ```
>  <jvm-options>[Azul-1.8.0u222|1.8.0u260]-XX:+UseOpenJSSE</jvm-options>
>  <jvm-options>[Dynamic Code Evolution-11.0.10|]-XX:HotswapAgent=core</jvm-options>
>  <jvm-options>[Dynamic Code Evolution-11.0.10|]-Xlog:redefine+class*=info</jvm-options>
> ```

now its ok

Answer (score 0):

Solution to Payara 5.184 / Netbeans 8.2 / Java 8 Not launching Payara:

in file:
\payara5\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml

Search for the unrecognized option UseOpenJSSE and comment that tag.
Repeat for each occurrence.

Repeat as well for subsequent errors might appear.

Good Luck!